# On refreshing angularjs page gives error of page not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have an angular application in which when I used

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` 
 for  removing #! , it works good. but when I refreshes the page it gives error that 
Get GET /c/electronic/computer/laptop not found which is my url

This is my app.js page

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req,res,next){

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});



app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};


  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my index page I putted all my functions and apis for firing queries where in models there had my mongodb's queries

```
var express         = require('express');
var router          = express.Router();
const mongoose      = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
Category            = require('./models/category');
Product             = require('./models/product');
http                = require('http');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/baazaronline');
var db = mongoose.connection;

router.get('/api/category', function(req, res){
    Category.getCategory(function(err, category){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(category);
    });
});

router.get('/api/product', function(req, res){
    Product.getProduct(function(err, product)  {
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
        res.json(product);
    })
});



router.get('/api/product/:_id', function(req, res){

    Product.getProductById(req.params._id, function(err, product){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(product);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this relates to this in the docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kasun, the reason that this is occurring is because you are trying to refresh the page from one of your sub routes (has nothing to do with ui-router).

Basically if you request `www.yourdomain.com/` you likely have your server setup to return `index.html` which bootstraps your angular app. Once the app has loaded, any further url changes take `html5Mode` into consideration and update your page via ui-router.

When you reload your page the angular app is no longer valid as it has not loaded yet, so if you are trying to load a sub route (for example: `www.yourdomain.com/someotherpage`), then your server does not know how to deal with `/someotherpage` and likely returns `404` or some other error.

What you need to do is configure your server to return your angular app for **all** routes. I primarily use node/express, so I do something like:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    // call all routes and return the index.html file here
}
```

*Note: I usually use something like this as a final catch all, however I also include other routes above it for things like requesting static files, web crawlers, and any other specific routes that need to be handled.*

Comment: I don't know where to put it. I show you my code. You get a look on it and please let me know

Comment: I had updated my code above.please get a look onto it and give me the solution.